# Check for null character C++

Tags: c++, pointers, null, char

I'm trying to test if the value stored in a particular memory address is NULL, I have this and in debug it's showing the char value in that address as '\0'.
Yet it's always skipping over this IF statement.

Is this the right syntax to use?
I have ensured that the address is set to null.

```
if (test->address + length == NULL)
{
    ..code..
}
```

Comment: `NULL` is a null pointer, `'\0'` is a null character.

Comment: What is the type of `address`?

Comment: What about using a [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) if you are in C++ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming `address` is a `char*` pointer (or a `char[]` array), you need to dereference it to access the `char` values. That's

```
*(test->address + length)
```

or equivalently

```
test->address[length]
```

Answer (score 4):

If I have understood you correctly then the valid statement will look like

```
if ( *( test->address + length ) == '\0' )
{
    ..code..
}
```

Or

```
if ( test->address[length] == '\0' )
{
    ..code..
}
```

provided that type of object test->address either defined as a character array or a pointer of type `char *`

Answer (score 1):

Of course it skips this `if`. That's because pointers arithmetic rules.

- `test->address` is a pointer
- `test->address + length` is `test->address + sizeof(T) * length`, where `T` is the type of `address`.

Change:

```
if (test->address + length == NULL)
{
    ..code..
}
```

to

```
if (test->address[length] == 0)
{
    ..code..
}
```